# Comment traduire l'« (evidence of knowing) falsity » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

> This ‘out of the horse’s mouth’ evidence of knowing **falsity** is not
> something we often see. [cette preuve directe de la connaissance ... n'est pas quelque chose que l'on rencontre souvent] (RonNell Andersen Jones, sur [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2023/02/23/media/fox-news-dominion-reliable-sources/index.html))

---

> Falsehood, Falseness, Falsity; untruth, fabrication, fiction.
> Instances may be quoted in abundance from old authors to show that the
> first three words are often strictly synonymous; but the modern
> tendency has been decidedly in favor of separating them, *falsehood*
> standing for the concrete thing, an intentional lie; *falseness*, for
> the quality of being guiltily false or treacherous: as, he is justly
> despised for his *falseness* to his oath; and *falsity*, for the quality
> of being false without blame: as, the falsity of reasoning. — *The
> Century Dictionary*, 1911. (commentaire sur l'emploi, *Wiktionary*, [falsity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/falsity))

Comment traduit-on « falsity » dans la phrase citée de Jones ou comment doit-on réaménager la phrase pour parvenir à l'exprimer ?

Answer (score 3):

C'est très difficile, on peut penser a des idiomatismes mais qui ne collent pas grammaticalement avec les éléments de la tournure anglaise et obligent à remanier la phrase.

- sciemment / en connaissance de cause ~= on sait que
- une intox / une fausse information ~= la fausseté / le caractère faux
- de première main; de sa propre bouche ~= *out of the horse's mouth*

> On ne tombe pas tous les jours sur un aveu d'intox de première main.

> On ne tombe pas tous les jours sur une preuve écrite où l'intéressé admet lui-même avoir transmis une intox.

> Il est rare d'obtenir l'aveu direct qu'un média relaie de fausses informations en toute connaissance de cause.

> Un média qui admet de sa propre bouche être au courant de l'intox, c'est le genre de preuve qu'on voit rarement.

Comment: Je préfère la 3e que je trouve la plus naturelle et qui conserve le mot _connaissance_. C'est une juriste qui s'exprime et la connaissance est possiblement centrale à la qualification de la faute, comme le serait l'intention avec le meurtre dans un contexte pénal, par exemple.